# iOS - NSURLConnection Asynchronous Request Works Once, Then Fails (hangs) on 2nd Attempt

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a login view that a user will use to login to my app.
I use an NSURLConnection Asynchrounous Request block to connect to my web service and pass data back and forth.

I am having a weird issue where if the user logs in the first time, it works fine. But if they logout, then try to log in again the request is sent but never responds (I setup alertviews for all scenarioes; i.e. timeout, data = nil, error != nil, etc.). It just sits there with the loading screen I display and never does anything.

Am I just missing something?

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){
             if( data != nil ) {
                  //Handle Data Here
                  .............    
             } else {
                 [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
                 loadingView = nil;
                 BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Network connection was successful, but there was a problem with data transfer.\nPlease try again."];
                 [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:nil];
                 [alert show];             }
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
             loadingView = nil;
             BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Network connection was successful, but there was a problem with data transfer.\nPlease try again."];
             [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:nil];
             [alert show];
         }
         else if (error != nil && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut){
             [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
             loadingView = nil;
             BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"The network request timed out.\nPlease check your internet connection and try again."];
             [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:nil];
             [alert show];
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
             loadingView = nil;
             BlockAlertView *alert = [BlockAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"There was a problem connecting to the network.\nPlease check your internet connection and try again."];
             [alert setCancelButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:nil];
             [alert show];
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved the problem. Was an issue with the delegate assignment I was using to notify my view that I finished handling/saving the response data and to perform the segue. Because the delegate was being set in viewDidLoad, when the next view appeared and took over the delegate, the login view lost the delegate control. Just had to move the delegate assignment to viewWillAppear (or viewDidAppear).